# Fortify :Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why am i getting this error in below code . How can i fix it. Suggestions Please

```
Session["LoginId"] = "0";
Session["LoginName"] = "";
Session["ParentID"] = "0";
Session["UserID"] = "";
Session["UserEmail"] = "";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624267/asp-net-bad-practices-non-serializable-object-stored-in-session)

Answer (score 1):

Only enable filters for .NET,.NET Core Aspx. 
If it does not work, write your own custom string class that implements ISerialazble. For .NET 4.0 although msdn claims that String has a Serializable attribute it does not have. After looking at String class in source code of microsoft.net , we could not see this attribute on String class itself.

The silly thing for fortify is it does not check [Serialazble] attr. It searches for ISerialazble implementation. You can check it by using fortify jars to decrypt its rules. Extended_dotnet rule has the  desc.structural.dotnet.asp_dotnet_bad_practices_non_serializable_object_stored_in_session"