# ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session

Tags: c#, serialization, fortify

I have a code like

```
Session["key"] = "value";
```

But it is considered as a bad practice according to Fortify SCA with the reason of "Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session".

Screenshot as below:
[image]

What is the best way to solve this?
How to make the string "value" to be serializable?

Comment: What makes you think a `string` is **not** serializable?

Comment: Because the warning that it was given. Somehow it says that my code there is not serializable.

Comment: Ignore it. It is a false alarm.

Comment: I would say that it is better to wrap the string into a class, instead of ignoring the warning. Moreover, I see that you have different values in `Session`, so they all can be wrapped into a single class, marked as `[Serializable]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a false positive.

From [Fortify document](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.dotnet.asp_dotnet_bad_practices_non_serializable_object_stored_in_session):

> In order for the session to be serialized correctly, all objects the application stores as session attributes must declare the `[Serializable]` attribute. Additionally, if the object requires custom serialization methods, it must also implement the `ISerializable` interface.

Since `string` doesn't implement `ISerializable`, it will not pass the check.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on it being a false positive. It is better to do something about it. I was getting the same report from Fortify. To fix it, when I was trying to set a session variable, I first ran the string through an object that I know is serialized. That class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PMPM.Helpers
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SessionHelper
    {
        public string SerializedString
        {
            get
            {
                return serializedStr;
            }
            set
            {
                serializedStr = value;
            }
        }
        private string serializedStr;
        public SessionHelper(string stringToSerialize)
        {
            serializedStr = stringToSerialize;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the class can be used like this:

```
Helpers.SessionHelper sessionHelper = new Helpers.SessionHelper("Welcome :" + " " + ds.Rows[0]["PortalWelcome"].ToString());
Session["UserInput"] = sessionHelper.SerializedString;
```

This will ensure that the object is serialized and will also satisfy Fortify.

Comment: I have tried this way and it has been resolved my problem, Thanks