# Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session for Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

Tags: .net, serialization, fortify

The below codes was flagged out as ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session. How do I resolve it ?

```
Session["MyUICulture"] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
Session["MyCulture"] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624267/asp-net-bad-practices-non-serializable-object-stored-in-session

Comment: Hi Kinjal, I know if is assigned to a string variable is a false positive. But how about the Session variable assigned to an CultureInfo Object?

Comment: Anyone got idea?